# How to disable “dynamic” browser title bar contents

Tags: browser, chromium

Quite a few web sites use the browser title bar/favicon to indicate changes they think I should be aware of (the most obvious example: I get a message in facebook, and the facebook tab of my browser starts blinking. That is both annoying and distracting)

So, how do I tell my (chromium) browser not to ever change the contents of the title bar of a tab unless I reload the page, or, alternatively, change it only when the tab in question is selected?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent websites from changing the contents of the title bar in your Chromium browser, two options come to mind:

**Option 1: Using browser extensions:**

1. Install an extension like "Disable HTML5 Autoplay" or "Tab Title Tweaker" from the Chrome Web Store.
2. Configure the extension's settings to prevent changes to the title bar. Each extension may have different options, so explore the available settings to find the desired behavior.

**Option 2: Modifying browser settings:**

1. Open a new tab in your Chromium browser.
2. Enter the following address in the address bar: chrome://flags.
3. On the Experiments page, use the search bar to find options related to "tab freeze" or "tab discarding".
4. Disable any options that are related to tab freezing, discarding, or title bar changes. Look for flags that may prevent tabs from being automatically updated.
5. After modifying the settings, restart your browser for the changes to take effect.

Please note that modifying experimental flags may have unintended consequences, so proceed with caution and be aware of potential side effects.